# Odd/Even datagridview rows background color

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datagridview

I have datagridview and now I would like to change background color of its each row depending whether row number is even or odd.

I thought that there must be easier way to reach that. Then using for example this part of code and modify it so it would change the colours of dtg's row. If this snippet of code is one of the ways to do that, may someone help me to improve it so it wouldn't throw exception when index is out if rabge?

```
public void bg_dtg()
    {
        try
        {

            for (int i = 0; i <= dataGridView1.Rows.Count ; i++)
            {
                if (IsOdd(i))
                {

                    dataGridView1.Rows[i].DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.LightBlue;
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(""+ex);
        }
    }

   public static bool IsOdd(int value)
   {
       return value % 2 != 0;
   }
```

Thank you for your time and answers.

Comment: This code wouldn't work if adding/removing rows unless we have to re-call the method.

Comment: @KingKing my app isn't that large so re-calling it like 3 times isn't that hard for me. Thanks for your comment.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are getting exception because you are accessing row that is not present. GridView rows are zero based `index`, it means if you have ten rows in grid the index will be from 0 to 9 and you should iterate one less then the rows `count`. The `i <= dataGridView1.Rows.Count` will give exception on last iteration because when count is 10 (total rows are ten) and dataGridView1.Rows[10] does not exists therefore exception is thrown.

*Change* <= in loop condition to <

```
for (int i = 0; i <= dataGridView1.Rows.Count ; i++)
```

*To*

```
for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count ; i++)
```

You Should [AlternatingRowsDefaultCellStyle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.alternatingrowsdefaultcellstyle.aspx) property to set alternative row style to keep it simple and efficient.

Comment: Hello, thank you, I forgot about that. Is there any easier way to change bgcolor of odd/even rows?

Comment: You can use alternatingrowsdefaultcellstyle, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.alternatingrowsdefaultcellstyle.aspx

Answer (score 31):

There is a `DataGridView` alternate row view style option in the forms designer. `AlternatingRowsDefaultCellStyle` in the properties grid

Comment: my gridview is taking alternate style by default i dont want that style how to disable AlternatingRowsDefaultCellStyle

Answer (score 5):

**you can try this code**

```
 for (int i = 0; i < GridView1.Rows.Count; i++) {

     if (i % 2 == 0) {
       GridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].Style.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Green;
       GridView1.Rows[i].Cells[1].Style.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Green;
     }
     else {
       GridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].Style.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
       GridView1.Rows[i].Cells[1].Style.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
     }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use `AlternatingRowsDefaultCellStyle`

**OR**

you can also do it manually

```
   foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)

            if (row.Index % 2==0 )
            {
                row.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Red;    
            }
```

Answer (score 4):

```
AlternatingRowStyle-BackColor = "#C5C5C5"
```

We can directly add the code in the ASP grid

```
<asp:GridView ID="Gridview1" runat="server"
                                 AlternatingRowStyle-BackColor = "#F3F3F3" 
                                AutoGenerateColumns="true">
</asp:GridView>
```